# PHP create button whit mySql DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-applications, server

I have a database with three tables "Cantiere "Affidataria "SubAffidataria"
"Cantiere" has a 1 to N relationship with Affidataria "Affidataria" has a 1 to N relationship with subAffidataria
so in Affidataria there is a fk of "Cantiere" called "fkIdCantiere" and in subAffidataria there is a fk of "Affidataria" called "fkIDAffidataria"
my problem is to go from a "function" to the id of fkIdAffidataria
in fact, if you notice in the screenshot you see the carers but not the sub-delegates. so I have to make sure to save the fkIdAffidataria to put it in the QUERY ..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i54G4.png)

"0 results" indicates that the query did not find any subAffidataria .. when in fact they are in the database

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["username"]))
    {
        header('location: ../index.php');
    }
    else
    {

?>
<?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "progettocantiere";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "my_progettocantiere";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $idCantiere = $_GET['idCantiere'];

        $sql1 = "SELECT idAffidataria,nomeCantiere,fkIDCantiere 
                FROM Affidataria 
                WHERE fkIDCantiere = '$idCantiere'";

        echo($idAffidataria);
        $idAffidataria = $_GET['idAffidataria'];
        $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

        if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo'<br><br><br>';
                echo '<h3>Affidataria</h3>';

                echo '<a class="myButton"    href="../../pagineHtml/visualizza/visualizzazione/affidatario.php?idAffidataria=' . $row["idAffidataria"] . '">' . $row["nomeCantiere"] . '</a>';
                echo '<a class="myButton"   href="../../pagineHtml/visualizza/visualizzazione/affidatario.php?idAffidataria=' . $row["idAffidataria"] . '">Stampa PDF ' . $row["nomeCantiere"] . '</a>';
                echo '<a class="myButton" href="../../pagineHtml/visualizza/visualizzazione/affidatario.php?idAffidataria=' . $row["idAffidataria"] . '">Esporta Directory Interna ' . $row["nomeCantiere"] . '</a>';
                echo '<a class="myButton" href="../../pagineHtml/visualizza/visualizzazione/affidatario.php?idAffidataria=' . $row["idAffidataria"] . '">Stampa Personale ' . $row["nomeCantiere"] . '</a>';
                echo '<a class="myButton" href="../../pagineHtml/visualizza/visualizzazione/affidatario.php?idAffidataria=' . $row["idAffidataria"] . '">Esporta Directory Personale ' . $row["nomeCantiere"] . '</a>';
                echo '<a class="myButton" href="../../pagineHtml/visualizza/visualizzazione/affidatario.php?idAffidataria=' . $row["idAffidataria"] . '">Stampa Mezzi ' . $row["nomeCantiere"] . '</a>';
                echo '<a class="myButton" href="../../pagineHtml/visualizza/visualizzazione/affidatario.php?idAffidataria=' . $row["idAffidataria"] . '">Esporta Directory Mezzi ' . $row["nomeCantiere"] . '</a>';

            }
            echo'<br><br><br>';


        } else {
            echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
//subAffidatario
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "progettocantiere";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "my_progettocantiere";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM SubAffidatario 
            WHERE fkIdAffidataria = '$idAffidataria'";

    echo($idSubAffidatario);
    $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

    if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo'<br><br><br>';
            echo '<a class="myButton" href="../../pagineHtml/visualizza/visualizzazione/subAffidatario.php?idSubAffidatario=' . $row["idSubAffidatario"] . '">' . $row["ragioneSocialeSubAffidatario"] . '</a>';
        }
        echo'<br><br><br>';
        echo '<a href="../../pagineHtml/inserimento/inserimentoGenerale/inserimentoCantiere.php" class="myButton" alt="Nuovo Cantiere +">Nuovo Cantiere +</a>';

    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>Progetto Cantiere</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../paginaIniziale/css/bootstrap-4.0.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Try to echo $idAffidataria before your second sql1. What does it return ?

Comment: @Yukirhodes echo it doesn't return anything to me, with alert (javascript) it gives me back the empty window

Comment: Then you probably should reaffect properly your variable when you are doing the second query : `$idAffidataria = $_GET['idAffidataria'];`. Just make sure that sql1 stores the query you want by echo-ing it too.

Comment: @Yukirhodes no man doesn't work … would not you be able to answer the question with the solution you proposed to me?
maybe I'm wrong to place the $ _GET and the echo ..

Comment: What I mean is to check if all your variables are set like you want. If you take a closer look at this line : `$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM SubAffidatario 
            WHERE fkIdAffidataria = '$idAffidataria'";`, is the table name correct (maybe SubAffidataria instead of SubAffidatario) ? Does the colomn fkIdAffidataria is spelled correctly ? Are the single quotes necessary for a FK btw (try without) ?

If everythink is ok, then it is coming from your database...